# Java Heapdump analysis - Get LOA objects

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap-dump, ibm-jvm

I am analyzing heapdump and GC logs from IBM JVM. The GC logs shows global GC being triggerred because LOA is filling up. I want to find out which objects are filling up LOA. How can I get that information from the heap dump. I am using MAT and ISA for the heap dump analysis. There are no objects with large enough shallow heap to be candidate for LOA.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the LOA is filling up? 
 These are the default settings:

```
-Xloainitial0.05 (5% of Heap)
-Xloaminimum0 (0%)
-Xloamaximum0.5 (50%)
```

So what is your MAX heap? What are the sizes of the Objects allocations ?
Can you post your JVM Parameters ?